# Why _effectiveValues member is array instead of just object in dependencyobject

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I understand that _effectiveValues [] is private member in Dependency object which is used to hold local value set by setter of dependency property.It could be just a object type to hold the setter value, why it is an array?

Comment: Can anyone answer this question?

Comment: Check the Reference Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,9b4ca0ed4a53f2ea

Comment: Could you please explain little bit,  I am not able to understand.